# Volley JsonObjectRequest sending 3 JSONObject in same request?

Tags: android, android-volley

I created a JsonObjectRequest that I use to send a JSONObject to my WebService. When I try send this JSONObject the object is sending but send 3 objects instead 1. Looking in my data base there's 3 objects added. 
I can't understand why this problem, because I always send 1 JSONObject but in webservice there's 3 objects.

I tried to use Postman of Google Chrome, and using Postman send 1 JSONObject normally.

What can be ?

**JsonObjectRequest**

```
public JsonObjectRequest sendContatoToEmpresa(String nome,
                                         String email,
                                         String telefone,
                                         String assunto,
                                         String mensagem,
                                         String idEmpresa,
                                         final ContatoAdapter listener){
        urlPost.append(WebServiceURL.getBaseWebServiceURL());
        urlPost.append("/ws/contatos/contatos/add.json");
        JSONObject jsObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject objs = new JSONObject();
            objs.put("nome", nome);
            objs.put("email", email);
            objs.put("telefone", telefone);
            objs.put("assunto", assunto);
            objs.put("mensagem", mensagem);
            objs.put("pessoa_id", idEmpresa);
            jsObject.put("Contato", objs);
            Log.i("JSONOBJECT->", jsObject.toString());
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("JSONException->", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        Log.i("URL CONTATO EMPRESA->", urlPost.toString());
        JsonObjectRequest apc = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                urlPost.toString(),
                jsObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        try {
                            Log.i("JSOBJECT->", jsonObject.toString());
                            if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("999")){
                                listener.isSend(true);
                            }else{
                                listener.isSend(false);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("JSONException->", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e("ERROR METHOD:", "sendContatoToEmpresa in ContatoDAO: " + volleyError.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String auth = new String(android.util.Base64.encode((BasicAuthenticationRest.USERNAME + ":" + BasicAuthenticationRest.PASSWORD).getBytes(), android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE | android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP));
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        return apc;
    }
```

**Activity**

```
public Integer sendContatoToEmpresa(String nome,
                                     String email,
                                     String telefone,
                                     String assunto,
                                     String mensagem,
                                     String idEmpresa){
        final int[] send = {0};

        if(nome.length() == 0 ||
                email.length() == 0 ||
                telefone.length() == 0 ||
                assunto.length() == 0 ||
                mensagem.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Informe todos os campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            send[0] = 0;
        }else{
            final ProgressDialog progress = new CustomProgressDialog().getCustomProgress(null, getView().getContext());
            progress.show();
            JsonObjectRequest app = new ContatoDAO().sendContatoToEmpresa(nome,
                    email,
                    telefone,
                    assunto,
                    mensagem,
                    idEmpresa,
                    new ContatoAdapter(){
                        @Override
                        public void isSend(Boolean value) {
                            if(value){
                                send[0] = 1;
                            }
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }
            });
            CustomVolleySingleton.getInstance(getView().getContext()).addToRequestQueue(app);
        }
        return send[0];
    }
```

**CustomVolleySingleton**

```
public class CustomVolleySingleton extends Application{

    private static CustomVolleySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";

    private CustomVolleySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CustomVolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {            
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following:

```
app.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Here you can change the timeout (MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS) and change the number of attempts (DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES)

Comment: MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, what do you recommend ?

Comment: Maybe you can try about 30000, that is 30 seconds, or more

Comment: my friend, there's any way to set `setRetryPolicy` like a default to all my requests or I will need to set it to each app ?

Comment: You can put this code into the addToRequestQueue method in your CustomVolleySingleton.class